# magento 2 cart page rules for free shipping not working

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, customer-group, free-shipping

I have two `customer groups` one is `general` another is `wholesaler` for this groups I need to enable `free shipping` for some specific price. For example if general customer subtotal is 100 means it will show free shipping. For whole sale the subtotal is 500 means it need to show free shipping please tell me how can I do it I tried below methods but still no luck.please help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Suggest that you  may have multiple for same products/items ,please check all Active rules

Comment: I am just using subtotal and customer group...Is this achievable from backend or need to work on code?